# SQL query to filter out users who already have recieved an email

Tags: sql, email, select, laravel-4, filter

Suppose:

1. You tried to send a mass mailing, but something went wrong, and only some users got the mail.
2. You sent a mass mailing recently, but now new users have signed up, and they need to receive the mail as well.

How do you filter those who have already received the news (via an Eloquent query or a select command from database .)

Actually I faced this problem in a project based on Laravel 4, I am searching for a query using Laravel Eloquent on a pivot table and keep track the sent emails to the users.

In my case there is two Model: Post and User

Its a many to many relationship: any user can receive many posts and any post can be sent to many users

Comment: Put a list of recent email addresses into a table, and check if they are in that table before sending the email?

Comment: emails are in the user table, I want to send the email to all of them, then next time when I want to send the same email, just new users can receive it. Many to many relationship, (every user can receive many emails and any email can be sent to many users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two Model: **Post** and **User**

Its a many to many relationship: any user can receive many posts and any post can be sent to many users

I implemented it as the following:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function recipients() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'posts_users', 'post_id', 'user_id');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function mails() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'posts_users', 'user_id', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

So, when I want to send a post to users I use

```
$usersToMail = User::whereNotExists(function($query) use ($post_id)
               {
                    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                          ->from('posts_users')
                          ->whereRaw('posts_users.user_id = users.id')
                          ->whereRaw('posts_users.post_id = '.$post_id);
               })->get();

foreach ($usersToMail as $user)
{
    // send email
    $user->mails()->save($post); // it records that this post has been sent to the user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add a column to your `users` table eg a `datetime` field called `mailed_at`. Then in your email or signup method (wherever it is you're sending that first email) update the user with the `datetime` they were emailed.

From then on you can query based on `mailed_at` for any users who still need an email.

---

To check for multiple users that need a newsletter, let's say your users table schema is as follows (keeping it simple):

```
id  |  email  |  password  |  mailed_at (nullable)
```

We check here whether a user has received an email by querying based on the mailed_at column. To get **all** users that need to receive a mailout you would do the following:

```
$usersToMail = User::whereNull('mailed_at')->get();
```

Comment: Maybe I mentioned my problem badly, because I think it must be a common task. suppose its a newsletter and I want to send the news to anyone who didn't receive it. your solution just work for one email not for many emails (news)

Comment: It just tells us some users didn't receive a news, but which news? in someway you must check the users against an specific news, actually I save the news in a Post table, and I use a pivot table between Users and Post to check which user has received which mail.

Comment: Ok, you really need to be explicit about what you're asking in your question. For anyone to answer you need to give *all* the info or you simply wont get the response you're after. I'd suggest making your question more specific in future as I have actually answered the question you've asked.

Comment: sorry, I think you are right, I reviewed my question and refined it, actually my english is not good and I copy paste some parts, now please check if the question is telling what I mean

Comment: please revert back your down vote. it just was a misunderstanding

Comment: I voted up your answer, hope you reconsider your vote the question and regard my own answer too.